# converting simple SOAP client code from php to python

Tags: python, django, soap

so here is my php code

```
    $client = new SoapClient('https://someservice.com/Tokens.xml', array('soap_version'   => SOAP_1_1));

    $params['merchantId'] = 'ABC';
    $params['invoiceNo'] = 1;
    $result = $client->__soapCall("MakeToken", array($params));
    $token = $result->MakeTokenResult->token;
```

so i've installed suds 
and i've came this far

```
from suds.client import Client
def test(request):
    client = Client(location="https://someservice.com/Tokens.xml" )
    return(HttpResponse('something !! '))
```

im not sure what the next step is in this line

```
$result = $client->__soapCall("MakeToken", array($params));
```

this is what i came up with which is obviusly wrong !

```
 client.service.__soapCall('MakeToken' , 'merchantId:ABC' , 'invoiceNo:1' )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `MakeToken` is the name of the method provided by the service, you need to call `client.service.MakeToken(merchantId='ABC', invoiceNo=1)`

Have a look at the documentation at https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation